# Repetitive authorization gives error 422 with Doorkeeper (Resource owner credentials flow)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, doorkeeper

I'm new in Rails and webdev. Trying to implement simple API for mobile app with Rails + Devise + Doorkeeper (like in https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-provider-app ).

Faced the problem that user can't make authorization request (POST /oauth/token) if he has already received token. I.e.:

```
curl -F grant_type=password -F username=1@tothetrip.com -F password=12345678 -X POST http://api.to_the_trip.dev/oauth/token
```

First time receiving:

```
{"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoyLCJlbWFpbCI6IjFAdG90aGV0cmlwLmNvbSJ9fQ.dYai6nH_KYb9YbDltqwFuzCO3i0igR_gw2T7u_TeVcI","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":7200,"created_at":1435864812}
```

Token goes to oauth_access_tokens table (what's not necessary for JWT, but not a problem).

If I repeat this request, i'll receive 422 error and rails' page with something like

```
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in Doorkeeper::TokensController#create
Validation failed: Token has already been taken

activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
doorkeeper (2.2.1) lib/doorkeeper/models/access_token_mixin.rb:76:in `find_or_create_for'
doorkeeper (2.2.1) lib/doorkeeper/oauth/request_concern.rb:33:in `find_or_create_access_token'
doorkeeper (2.2.1) lib/doorkeeper/oauth/password_access_token_request.rb:30:in `before_successful_response'
doorkeeper (2.2.1) lib/doorkeeper/oauth/request_concern.rb:7:in `authorize'
doorkeeper (2.2.1) lib/doorkeeper/request/password.rb:19:in `authorize'
doorkeeper (2.2.1) app/controllers/doorkeeper/tokens_controller.rb:42:in `authorize_response'
doorkeeper (2.2.1) app/controllers/doorkeeper/tokens_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

Even if i revoke token with POST /oauth/revoke, everything will be the same, except revoking timestamp in oauth_access_tokens. And that's very strange.

I investigate it a bit and find piece of code in doorkeeper gem (access_token_mixin.rb):

```
def find_or_create_for(application, resource_owner_id, scopes, expires_in, use_refresh_token)
        if Doorkeeper.configuration.reuse_access_token
          access_token = matching_token_for(application, resource_owner_id, scopes)
          if access_token && !access_token.expired?
            return access_token
          end
        end
        create!(
          application_id:    application.try(:id),
          resource_owner_id: resource_owner_id,
          scopes:            scopes.to_s,
          expires_in:        expires_in,
          use_refresh_token: use_refresh_token
        )
      end
```

So, the error is in create! method, which says that we tried to add duplicate (in stacktrace). And if i set reuse_access_token in Doorkeeper.configure, then it's ok. But i'll receive the same token after each authorization, what is very unsecure, as i understand. And yes, if i manually delete token from oauth_access_tokens, then i'll be able to auth.

So what's wrong?

My Doorkeeper config:

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use.
  # Currently supported options are :active_record, :mongoid2, :mongoid3,
  # :mongoid4, :mongo_mapper
  orm :active_record

  resource_owner_authenticator do
    current_user || env['warden'].authenticate!(:scope => :user)
  end

  resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
    request.params[:user] = {:email => request.params[:username], :password => request.params[:password]}
    request.env["devise.allow_params_authentication"] = true
    user = request.env['warden'].authenticate!(:scope => :user)
    env['warden'].logout
    user
  end

  access_token_generator "Doorkeeper::JWT"
end

Doorkeeper.configuration.token_grant_types << "password"

Doorkeeper::JWT.configure do
#JWT config
end
```

Routes:

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  use_doorkeeper
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json}, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, :only => [:show, :create, :update]

      get '/me' => "credentials#me"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if u want to find an answer then just formulate a question.

Problem was in default implementation of Doorkeeper::JWT token. It doesn't have any randomness in payload, so it was always the same for every user's authentication. So i added:

```
Doorkeeper::JWT.configure do
  token_payload do |opts|
    user = User.find(opts[:resource_owner_id])
    {
      iss: "myapp",  #this
      iat: DateTime.current.utc.to_i,   #this
      rnd: SecureRandom.hex,   #and this

      user: {
        id: user.id,
        email: user.email
      }
    }
  end

  secret_key "key"

  encryption_method :hs256
end
```

And it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the selected answer, so I'll add another answer to suggest an improvement.

Instead of creating the `rnd` claim, which is subject to name collisions, use the `jti` reserved claim since it's meant to provide a unique identifier for the JWT. I also recommend using a UUID instead of Hex for the `jti` value.

```
Doorkeeper::JWT.configure do
  token_payload do |opts|
    user = User.find(opts[:resource_owner_id])
    {
      iss: "myapp",
      iat: DateTime.current.utc.to_i,
      jti: SecureRandom.uuid,

      user: {
        id: user.id,
        email: user.email
      }
    }
  end

  secret_key "key"

  encryption_method :hs256
end
```

[You can read more about JWT reserved claims here.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-jones-json-web-token-07#page-7)